# Install zfs on debian 9 stretch

Tags: debian, apt, zfs

I tried to install zfs on debian 9.1, however I'm experiencing some errors.

My first installation was only of zfs-dkms however I read on the net that also the spl-dkms is required for zfs-dkms to run.

---

My steps were to change my **sources.list** adding the ***contrib non-free*** as follows:

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Done a classic apt-get update and then tried installing zfs with the following:

```
apt-get install spl-dkms
```

and only after

```
apt-get install zfs-dkms
```

---

As a result, I have these errors:

```
root@debian:/etc/apt# apt-get install zfs-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-zed zfsutils-linux

...

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up libzpool2linux (0.6.5.9-5) ...
Setting up libzfs2linux (0.6.5.9-5) ...
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.9-5) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.wants/zfs-import-cache.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cac
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-import-cache.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.serv
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.wants/zfs-mount.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-mount.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-share.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zfs.target â /lib/systemd/system/zfs.target.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
zfs-mount.service couldn't start.
Job for zfs-share.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status zfs-share.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
zfs-share.service couldn't start.
Setting up zfs-zed (0.6.5.9-5) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zed.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-zed.service â /lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
```

Reading **journalctl -xe** as suggested I get:

```
root@debian:/etc/apt# journalctl -xe
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-share.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start ZFS file system shares.
-- Subject: Unit zfs-share.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit zfs-share.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-share.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-share.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
-- Subject: Unit zfs-mount.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit zfs-mount.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian zfs[81481]: The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian zfs[81481]: Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
-- Subject: Unit zfs-mount.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit zfs-mount.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[1]: Starting ZFS file system shares...
-- Subject: Unit zfs-share.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit zfs-share.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 23:13:13 debian systemd[81483]: zfs-share.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/rm: No such file or direc
-- Subject: Process /usr/bin/rm could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The process /usr/bin/rm could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 2.
```

What's wrong here? I missed something else? How is the **zfs-linux** package related to zfs installation?

**What is the correct way to install zfs in debian 9 ?**

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status | grep zfs` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual answer by @cas is good but have some corrections to be applied.

So let's take a fresh installation of Debian 9 and assuming that the **contrib non-free** repositories are also not enabled.

---

### Step 0 - Enable the contrib non-free repositories

I used `sed` to find and replace the word *main* inside `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sed -i 's/main/main contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update
```

---

### Step 1 - ZFS Installation

Since the last fixes `spl-dkms` is correctly seen as `zfs-dkms` dependency so it's recalled automatically and it's not necessary to install it manually before `zfs-dkms`. The symbolic link is needed due to a bug inside the zfs distribution in Debian, that doesn't look for `rm` binary in the right position.

```
apt -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

ln -s /bin/rm /usr/bin/rm

apt-get -y install zfs-dkms
```

---

### Step 2 - ZFS Restart

At this point zfs-dkms is installed but it throws errors in `journalctl -xe`; to start zfs properly use:

```
/sbin/modprobe zfs

systemctl restart zfs-import-cache
systemctl restart zfs-import-scan
systemctl restart zfs-mount
systemctl restart zfs-share
```

---

### Step 3 - YOU MUST CREATE AT LEAST ONE ZPOOL

At this point I discovered **that YOU must create a zpool before reboot** otherwise zfs will not load the proper modules if there are no zpools. It's a sort of saving resources mechanism ( but even in that case this will still throw errors inside `journalctl -xe` )

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864348

> *" We are not doing this because ZFS modules would taint the kernel, if
>   there's no zpool available then it shouldn't be loaded. "*

If you miss this part you have to start from **Step 2**

For example, by using the example provided by @cas, you can create this file based zpool or directly create your disk based ones.

```
truncate -s 100M /root/z1
truncate -s 100M /root/z2
zpool create tank /root/z1 /root/z2
zpool scrub tank
zpool status
```

then after a `reboot` everything will work with no errors in `journalctl -xe`

Answer (score 4):

Slight variations for me on Debian 9.4 - after the Apt sources additions:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-amd64       # not tied to specific kernel version
apt-get install zfs-dkms zfsutils-linux   # my apt recommends is off

lsblk                                     # double-check which disks to pool

zpool create -f jeff -o ashift=12 -o autoexpand=on -o autoreplace=on mirror sdb sdd
zfs set mountpoint=/var/jeff jeff
zfs set compression=lz4 jeff
zfs create jeff/blog
zfs create jeff/docs
zfs create jeff/pics
zfs set compression=off jeff/pics

df -h
```

The mount was **NOT** present sigh - discovered that there was an existing `/var/jeff` with content - moved that out of the way and did a `reboot`...

After reboot:

```
df -htzfs
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
jeff              849G  128K  849G   1% /var/jeff
jeff/blog         850G  128K  849G   1% /var/jeff/blog
jeff/docs         856G  128K  849G   1% /var/jeff/docs
jeff/pics         850G  128K  849G   1% /var/jeff/pics
```

**Hooray** - all present and bit-rot protected :)

Comment: +1 but strongly recommend using `/dev/disk/by-id/?` rather than `/dev/sd?` devices.  Either use the by-id names when creating the pool, or fix later with `zpool export <pool>` followed by `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ <pool>`.   These names, unlike /dev/sd*, WILL persist across reboots.  Also, if you have a label printer, you can print labels with short versions of the by-id device names (there's usually a serial number portion of the name which makes a good, short, unique label) and label the drives to make them easy to identify if they ever need to be replaced.

Comment: Ummm - but ZFS doesnt care about the disk aliases used during create - all the info is written to zfs-part9 on the disk - and that is what is used to construct the array. I don't really care whether what was /dev/sdb changes to something else in the future, and I always check with `lsblk -f` just before dickering with drive hardware - for our production servers the Dell hdd blink tool is useful in relating the current os-alias to the physical unit :) - I think the /dev/disk/by-id is more useful for other mounting systems that don't have ZFS's built in consistency - e.g. fstab.

Comment: using by-id will give you meaningful/useful names (identifying each drive's brand, model, and serial number) in `zpool` command like `status` and `list`, which can be easily copy-pasted into any necessary zpool offline/detach/replace/etc commands.   `sda` doesn't tell you anything useful.  `ata-ST4000VN008-2DR166_ZDH35XXX` identifies exactly what kind of drive it is and its serial number. You can still get the (current) short dev names if you ever want them using the `-L` option with `zpool list`, `zpool status`, etc (in my experience, mostly useful with `zpool list -L -v`).

Comment: IME, the meaningful names help to reduce human error.  It's easy to mistype, e.g.,  sdd as sdf.  much harder to mistype a by-id name.

Comment: Lol - lots of folks make the same recommendation - I personally find it easier to remember and type sdc sde sdf and sdg. We buy disks in batches and they all start with the same 48 or so by-id chars and just have 2-4 digit suffixes that differ. People don't type by-id names - they use tab-completion - more likely to lead to an oops IMHO. I find differentiating one letter in a three-char much easier than 2-4 digits in a 52 char name. I know that lots of folks also recommend UUID. As ZFS doesn't care, I think I will stick to what I find easier - less is sometimes more :)

Answer (score 3):

I just created a brand new stretch VM to test this.   Minimal install (just ssh and standard system tools), edit sources.list to add contrib and non-free, then:

```
apt-get install spl-dkms zfs-dkms
```

You may also want to manually install `zfsutils-linux`.  It should be installed automatically when you install `zfs-dkms` but the dependencies may vary for different Debian releases and for different versions of the Debian ZoL packages:

```
apt-get install  zfsutils-linux
```

It looks as if there's a bug in the systemd unit file for `zfs-share`.  It's trying to run `/usr/bin/rm` instead of `/bin/rm`.

The quick fix is to run `ln -s /bin/rm /usr/bin`, or alternatively:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
cp -a /lib/systemd/system/zfs-share.service .
edit zfs-share.service and change `/usr/bin/rm` to `/bin/rm`
```

and then restart the zfs services:

```
systemctl restart zfs-import-cache
systemctl restart zfs-import-scan
systemctl restart zfs-mount
systemctl restart zfs-share
```

NOTE: I manually ran `modprobe zfs` before restarting any of the zfs services.  I'm not sure if they'll do that automatically or not, so you may need to do that too.

BTW, you probably want to `apt-get install zfs-initramfs` too, to ensure that zfs is loaded during the initramfs.

---

I tested that this works with:

```
# truncate -s 100M /root/z1
# truncate -s 100M /root/z2
# zpool create tank mirror /root/z1 /root/z2 

# zfs set compression=lz4 tank
# rsync -ax /etc /tank/
# du -sch /etc /tank/etc/
3.5M    /etc
825K    /tank/etc/
4.3M    total

# zpool scrub tank
# zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h0m with 0 errors on Thu Aug  3 19:28:21 2017
config:

    NAME          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0    ONLINE       0     0     0
        /root/z1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        /root/z2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

The zpool is working and /tank is automounted after a reboot.

Conclusion: it works now.

---

BTW, this stretch VM uses a ZFS zvol created on my main `sid` system as its disk.  I made a snapshot of it immediately after the initial installation, before installing spl-dkms and zfs-dkms so I could quickly revert and start again if anything major went wrong.

I first made the zvol with only 1GB and needed to increase it later to have enough space for build-essential, linux-headers-amd64 etc:

```
# zfs list -r -t all export/volumes/stretch
NAME                                         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
export/volumes/stretch                      6.25G   834G  1.77G  -
export/volumes/stretch@2017-08-03-18:31:04   279M      -  1.09G  -
```

setting `compression=lz4` on tank in the VM is probably worse than useless - the zvol already has lz4 compression on it.

Comment: I tried to install it on a fresh new vm but I'm experiencing still problems i guess.. some services aren't starting correctly.. As far I can see the ZFS DKMS bug list is filled of "can't install" bugs reports. I wonder if is normal that developers let months pass after such many bugfix requests reproducible just with apt-get install zfs-dkms ..

Comment: On the part where you ask for the cd directory you meant: /etc/systemd/system/ ? because /etc/systemd/service is non existant.. also i have this message: "Failed to restart zfs-import-mount.service: Unit zfs-import-mount.service not found." and "Failed to restart zfs-import-share.service: Unit zfs-import-share.service not found."

Comment: It seems i have also problems with ZFS-ZED service by reading journalctl -xe: Aug 11 23:03:23 debian zed[70734]: ZFS Event Daemon 0.6.5.9-5 (PID 70734)
Aug 11 23:03:23 debian zed[70734]: Failed to initialize libzfs
Aug 11 23:03:23 debian systemd[1]: zfs-zed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 11 23:03:23 debian systemd[1]: zfs-zed.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 11 23:03:23 debian systemd[1]: zfs-zed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Have things changed/improved with Debian 10? And if so, should I post a separate question for Debian 10?